# How to dynamically switch between image and video based on window width?

Tags: jquery, html, image, hover, html5-video

My current code shows a unique image based on what the screen width is, which acts as a link a video.

```
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eabq2KCvhYo&feature=youtu.be">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="/wp-content/uploads/core-images/thumbnails/showreel_clicker_small.png">
                    <source srcset="/wp-content/uploads/core-images/thumbnails/showreel_clicker_medium.png" media="(min-width: 500px)">
                    <source srcset="/wp-content/uploads/core-images/thumbnails/showreel_clicker_large.png" media="(min-width: 850px)">

                    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/core-images/thumbnails/showreel_clicker_large.png" alt="alt text" width="100%" height="100%">
                </picture>
            </a>
```

What I've been trying to do now is to replace the last image (showreel_clicker_large.png) with a preview video that plays on mouse hover. My biggest problem is that I don't know how to make the video appear only if the window size is wider than 850px (a likely desktop width). My rather simple minded attempts using `media="(min-width:)` so far have just resulted in separate elements for the video and the image.

I assume some JQuery is necessary but I don't have much knowledge in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var screenwidth = $(window).width(); //get browser window resolution
if(screenwidth > 850) {
  //appear video
} else {
}
```

Comment: Not a terribly in depth answer, but I've it put me on the right track (I think). A winner is you.